VS Code. Как экспортировать полученный результат от Сравнения двух файлов
Проблема состоит в том, что у меня возникают трудности с экспортом результата сравнения двух файлов, который содержит выделенные хайлайты (красный, зеленый цвет и т.д.). Я хотел бы экспортировать этот результат в формате HTML, а затем сохранить его в PDF. Но я не знаю, как это сделать и ищу помощи и рекомендации по этому вопросу.


вы знаете, как выложить картинку в интернеты, но не знаете, как вставить эту же картинку в pdf-файл?

прекрасное решение, особенно если код состоит из 3к + строчек + второй файл

Если Вам нужно удобное и стандартное решение воспользуйтесьgit diff он создаст 1 текстовый файл где плюсами будут начинаться добавленные строки а минусами удаленные. I

К сожалению, использование git diff - это не то, что мне нужно
